# Prevent word from suggesting save of dotx in global template folder

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have a problem, well, more of an annoyance.

It is very often for me to have to **take a .docx document and convert it into a .dotx**

As soon as I choose the "Word Template (.dotx)" file type, Word takes me to "**Custom Office Templates**" folder and I **lose the context** of my current folder.

I have even created a shortcut there to let me go straight to c:\temp, but ideally, I would like to have Word stay wherever it was.

Is this possible?

P.S. registry tricks are welcome

[image]

Comment: This is not actually a programming question. I propose to close it or move it to an appropriate site. Anyway have you tried to change: `Word Options`->`Advanced`->`File Locations` ?

Comment: probably should have posted in super user. anyway, that is actually really helpful. I can customize the folder I want for each batch of files I have to convert. thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've created an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change paths in

`Word Options`->`Advanced`->`File Locations`